# SAS Excel add-in

Tags: excel, sas

How do I make a data table I just created to show in my excel sheet using Excel add-in 7.1?

I for example pull some columns out of an existing table to create a new table.

```
data temp1;
 set temp;
  keep maturity counterparty rating product;
run;
```

I would now like to display "temp1" in the work sheet. When I run the code, it simply fills a cell saying ""Program1" executed at 21/05/2018 15:56:39.".

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this code inside a Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code inside a stored procedure in Excel, you just need to add `proc print` to your code:

```
proc print data=temp1; run;
```

Or You can save the table to a permeate library and register it in SAS Management console and save to a sas folder, then in Excel you can open the table directly.